# Dynamic character entry into cell pre carriage return

Tags: vba, dynamic

I'm looking to use a Worksheet_change event to dynamically insert a hypen after a third number is typed into a cell. The trigger for the insertion of the hyphen is typing of the third number without a following carriage return. I will then type a further three numbers, the third of which will be the trigger to insert a second hyphen to end up with the following . . . 123-456-789 
 I do not want the trigger of the hyphen insertion to be the final carriage return - I can code that thanks.
Many thanks in anticipation.

```
Dim strWord As String
Dim lngNumberOfCharacters As Long
StrWord = ActiveCell.Value
lngNumberOfCharacters = Len(strWord)
If lngNumberOfCharacters = 3 Then
strWord = (strWord & "-")
ActiveCell.Value = strWord
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that is something possible with Excel, I am not sure we have access to the characters you are typing BEFORE a carriage return. In the sense the value is not saved until you hit carriage return. Also You dont really need Worksheet_change event for this, you can set it up in Cell format>Custom>"###-###-###".  The cell will auto change its format.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no trigger that would fire on key press. `Worksheet_change` fires when the `range` is edited AND edit confirmed.

Plus, what you are trying to achieve can be done more easily by special number formatting (Format cell -> Custom).